# Permanent redirect to subfolder with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, redirect

I'm setting up a Symfony2 project on a Shared Host and I'm having some issues getting things done. Symfony2 by default has their dispatch controllers or main files (what in many system is the file `index.php`) inside `/web` directory so if I move all the project to `public_html` on the shared hosting then it won't works until I append the `/web` to the end on the URL. This is bad and noise for users since they know the page for it's domain. I'm trying to make the redirect using `.htaccess` as follow:

```
//301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*) /web/$1

//Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes
```

But it's not working since the hosting said that this lines are bad in the .htaccess file, then how I can get ride of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In root .htaccess you can use this `mod_rewrite` rule:

```
//Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((?!web/).*)$ /web/$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You know when you buy some hosting and you make your first FTP to it in your favourite client?

You might see something like this:

```
/
    ftp/
    httpdocs/
    access_log.txt
```

The `web/` directory is the `httpdocs/` in this scenario.  Sometimes the directory is called `public_html`, `www`, or just `html`.

They are all the same thing in the end of the day.

In your symfony project, the `app/`, `src/`, `vendor/` directories are supposed to sit behind the public root directory.

Normally on controlled servers you can create virtual hosts where you specify the document root. However if you are trying to get a website uploaded, move everything up to the parent directory and rename the web directory to what server is set up to use.